# android emulator browser  not connecting to internet

Tags: android, browser

my emulator browser not connecting to internet? how to do the settings?

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".reader"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
    </manifest>
```

Comment: This error doesn't look to be a cause of WebView not loading the page. are you able to load the same page in Android browser?

Comment: @Sheikh yes you are right! quest edited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited avd with value "GPS support= yes" and restarted the emulator. now working....

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed out `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` inside your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Follows following instruction
1. Firstly You check at your emulator that your emulator have Internet if not then 
2. Go to setting and then 
3. Go to wireless and network then 
4. wi-fi setting and on it and 
5. Save the setting and close the emulator again start and enjoy internet on your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to set an apn aswell, if you are behind a proxy.